# EditText onfocuschange is called but HasFocus not returns false when a Button is clicked

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

i have a listview in my activity which dynamics add items and i have a EditText which has setOnFocusChangeListener as :

```
 holder.productQTYTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus){
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                        ((ListItem)myItems.get(position)).productQTY = Caption.getText().toString();
                    }
                }
            });
```

this is how it looks :
[image]

as u can see the code saves the EditText value in a list but only if focus is lost ei `!hasFocus`

**EDIT:  this the res of the activity  the list is in Parent `linearLayout` While buttons in Child**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/txtSelectedClient" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Client"
            android:id="@+id/o_btnSelect"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Product"
            android:id="@+id/o_btnAdd"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/o_btnSave"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/orderList" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**focusing other EditText in List fires it but clicking button do not**

Comment: How did you conclude it never return false?
`put Log.d(TAG, hasFocus ? "hasFocus is true" : "hasFocus is false");`
before `if (!hasFocus)`

Comment: i set the breakpoint at `final int position = v.getId()` , anyway it fires after the `onClick` of the button is executed. but not the time it was clicked, focus should be lost as soon as i clicked the button not after it gets executed

Comment: The reason I ask to put the Log is because I suspect that it did return false on hasFocus, but different timing.
Also, `final int position = v.getId();` might have same id for listitems which can cause other issues.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)

Comment: as i told it return False But After Executing The Onclick of the Button

Answer (score -1):

why do you don't use a TextChangeListener instead of the FocusListener (see [TextChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)). You could request in the onClick method the focus for your button. Then the FocusChange is triggered. (I would prefer the TextChangeListener)

**Edit**

Back to the idea with the TextChangeListener.

Create a new (inner) class

```
class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final View mView;
    private final Type?! mMyItems;

    public CustomTextWatcher(View view, Type?! myItems) {
        mView = view;
        mMyItems = myItems;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        final int position = mView.getId();
        final EditText Caption = (EditText) mView;
        ((ListItem)myItems.get(position)).productQTY = Caption.getText().toString();

    }
}
```

Just register the TextWatcher:

```
holder.productQTYTxt.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(holder.productQTYTxt, myItems));
```

Comment: i am using a custom Adapter for ListView so i want to save the Edited Text in the same position as in the list, TextChangeListener returns `Editable` not `View` that way i dont get the position, any other way i can get position ?

Comment: What is with change the focus to the button? Or loop on all your EditText and find the focused one. If you've find the correct one, do the processing from FocusChanged, again.

Comment: i doing something like this http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/  check the 3rd code snippet

Comment: I added a possible solution (see Edit). I don't know if the recycling of view is a problem for your implementation.